# How to get alternative info from a routing namespace in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, namespaces, routes

Imagine you are working on a f,acebook(to skip the g,f,w) like site, and you need some routes like:

- `www.mydomain.com/ihome/jim/posts`
- `www.mydomain.com/ihome/jim/post/3`
- `www.mydomain.com/ihome/jim/posts/3/edit`.

Then how to set the routes to get the 'jim' part? I know I can use the following if there is no account part:

```
namespace :ihome do
  resources :posts
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick (untested) answer is : use the scope, it will give you a params[:user]

```
namespace :ihome do
  scope ":user" do
    resources :posts
  end
end
```

Have a look at the docs here : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#defining-defaults